# PHP OOP: Unique method per argument type?

Tags: php, oop, orm, documentation

I'm writing a little homebrew ORM (academic interest). I'm trying to adhere to the TDD concept as a training exercise, and as part of that exercise I'm writing documentation for the API as I develop the class.

Case in point - I'm working on a classic "getCollection" type mapper class. I want it to be able to retrieve collections of asset X (let's say blog posts) for a specific user, and also collections based on an arbitrary array of numeric values. So - you might have a method like any one of these

```
$User = $UserMapper->load(1);
$ArticleCollection = $ArticleMapper->getCollection(range(10,20));
$ArticleCollection = $ArticleMapper->getCollection($User);
$ArticleCollection = $ArticleMapper->getCollection($User->getId());
```

So, in writing the documentation for the getCollection method - I want to declare the @param variable in the Docblock. Is it better to have a unique method for each argument type, or is it acceptable to have a method that delegates to the correct internal method/class based on argument type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is acceptable to have a method that delegates to the correct internal method. You could document it like this:

```
@param Array|User|Integer $argName optional explanation
```

but then again, there is no one hindering you having one method each

```
public function getCollectionByRange(array $range)
public function getCollectionByUser(User $user)
public function getCollectionByUserId($id)
```

In addition, you could use the [magic `__call` method](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) to pretend the above methods exist and then capture method calls to them and delegate to your internal methods ([ZF does that f.i. for finding dependant database rows](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html#zend.db.table.relationships.fetching.dependent)). You would document these methods with the `@method` annotation in the Class DocBlock. But keep in mind that the magic methods are always slower over having and/or calling the appropriate methods directly.

Use what you think makes most sense for your application and usecase.

Answer (score 1):

It *sounds* like you want to do function overloading, but PHP (even PHP5) does not do overloading like you would in, say Java. The [Overloading section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) in the PHP manual is not [function overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading):

> Note: PHP's interpretation of
>   "overloading" is different than most
>   object oriented languages. Overloading
>   traditionally provides the ability to
>   have multiple methods with the same
>   name but different quantities and
>   types of arguments.

You might mean this:

```
class ArticleMapper {
   public function getCollection($param) {
      if (is_array($param)) { $this->getCollectionByArray($param); }
      if (is_int($param)) { $this->getCollectionByInt($param); }
      if (is_a($param, 'User')) { $this->getCollectionByUser($param); }
   }
   private function getCollectionByArray(array $param) { ... }
   private function getCollectionByInt($param) { ... }
   private function getCollectionByUser(User $param) { ... }
}
```

This seems like the a good way to do it to my eye.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate the answer, and very close to my initial implementation. What I am curious to know is, from an OOP best practices perspective, is it better to use a unique method re: responsibilities?

Comment: Ah, good point: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php I'll remove that errant `int` from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve something like [method overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) by checking the type of the passed parameter at runtime (PHP does not support this concept known from other languages like ADA, Java, C# or C++ e.g.):

```
[...]
/**
 * @param  User|array|integer $user
 * @return array
 */
public function getCollection($user) {
    // perhaps a switch-case would be better here
    if ($user instanceof User) {
        // do what has to be done if you passed in a User object
    } else if (is_int($user) {
        // do what has to be done if you passed in a user id
    } else if (is_array($user)) {
        // do what has to be done if you passed in an array of user ids
    }
}
[...]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer - however, I'm less interested in the how, rather in the why (or what is considered "best practice")

Comment: "Use what you think makes most sense for your application and usecase." - Gordon added this 26 minutes ago I think. There is no best-approach I think, as most of the time: it depends. I personally would go for the one-method-approach because it keeps the API uncluttered.